# Determining child index in it's parent

Tags: jquery

How can I determine index of an element in it's parent? Assume you have following DOM structure and you have set a *click* event listener for child divs. When each of them is clicked, I want to know it's index regarding the parent div.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To get an index in of an elements in its parent (amongst siblings really) use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) without any parameters, for example:

```
$(".child").click(function() {
  alert("Index: " + $(this).index());
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fY6SU/).