# JQuery - Determining parent index from its children

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-traversal

Good morning.
I drink some more coffee to compensate the stress with this Javascript/jQuery problem.

basically its the opposite thing of this question: [Determining child index in it's parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421303/determining-child-index-in-its-parent)

**The actual HTML (DOM)**

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div class="contentbox">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Image Gallery Header</h2>
            <div class="imageGallery">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prevImg"><i class="sx028"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="g2i1">
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery1.jpg" alt="" width="505" height="298" />
                            <p>Image Caption...</p>
                        </li>
                        <li id="g2i2">
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery2.jpg" alt="" width="505" height="298" />
                            <p>Image Caption...</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nextImg" title="nächstes Bild"><i class="sx029"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prevImg">&nbsp;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery1.jpg" alt="" width="149" height="88" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery2.jpg" alt="" width="149" height="88" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>            
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nextImg">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Image Gallery Caption</h2>
            <p>
                Some text.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Image Gallery Header</h2>
            <div class="imageGallery">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prevImg"><i class="sx028"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="g2i1">
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery4.jpg" alt="" width="505" height="298" />
                            <p>Image Caption...</p>
                        </li>
                        <li id="g2i2">
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery5.jpg" alt="" width="505" height="298" />
                            <p>Image Caption...</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nextImg"><i class="sx029"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prevImg">&nbsp;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery4.jpg" alt="" width="149" height="88" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="imgs/imageGallery5.jpg" alt="" width="149" height="88" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>            
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nextImg">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Image Gallery Caption</h2>
            <p>
                Some text.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thank you for reading that big pile.

**Pseudo JQuery**

```
$(".nextImg").click(function() { 
    var activeGallery = $(this).parents(".imageGallery").index();
    alert("You've clicked the next image button of image Gallery #" + activeGallery);
});
```

**Result (alert message)**

*You've clicked the next image button of image Gallery #1* <-- if you clicked the ".nextImg" button of the ".imageGallery" with the index(); of 1

*You've clicked the next image button of image Gallery #2* <-- if you clicked the ".nextImg" button of the ".imageGallery" with the index(); of 2

**Question:**

How do I "climb" up the parents of *class="nextImage"* to an element *div class="imageGallery"* and response the index of the *div class"imageGallery"* ?

Its really important for the last step of my gallery project. Thank you for any response!

Comment: i have done this but i dont have any code now. Try and use the .next() method from the root node. I will try and post answer later.. there is something else you need too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
$(".nextImg").click(function() { 
    var $galleries=$('.imageGallery');
    var activeGallery = $galleries.index($(this).closest(".imageGallery"));
    alert("You've clicked the next image button of image Gallery #" + activeGallery);
});
```

`activeGallery` will tell you the index position of the current `.imageGallery` (the one that includes the link that was clicked) among all the `.imageGallery`s. This is zero-based, so you might want to +1 for human readability.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you asked for, but I think it's exactly what you need:

```
$(".nextImg").click(function() { 
    var $activeGallery = $(this).closest(".imageGallery");
    // In here, you call methods on $activeGallery
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

```
var activeGallery = $(this).closest(".content").index();
```

I think maybe this is what you're after, you have to go up another level, `.content` is the div which is indexed in scope of the whole doument, from there you can target it's child gallery

Comment: If there are no other elements other than `.content`s in `.contentbox`.